# How to set zoomLevel in google Visualization Map api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement visualization map api,following this link https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map

i am successfully drawing the point on the google map but not able to set the zoomlevel.
For single point the zoomlevel automatic set to 19(max level).

my code:-

```
var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

map.draw(data, {showTip: true, zoom:14,  mapType: 'normal', useMapTypeControl:true, enableScrollWheel:false});
```

I have tried this `map.setZoom(12)` but its not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the property that defines the zoom-level in `google.visualization.Map` is not **`zoom`**,

it's called **`zoomLevel`** (funny, the title of your question contains the correct answer^^)

---

However, it's curious that the visualization-API does not provide a method to access the underlying `google.maps.Map`-instance.

You may add such a method (on your own risk), add this to the onload-callback:

```
google.visualization.Map.prototype.getMap=function(){
  for(var k in this){
   if(this[k].constructor==google.maps.Map)return this[k];
  }
}
```

you now may access the `google.maps.Map`-instance by calling the method `getMap` of the `google.visualization.Map`-instance.

Example:

```
map.getMap().setZoom(12);
```

Comment: thanks, i got your point in google.visualization.Map zoom is not the required poperty. as you suggested i change the zoom to zoomLevel its working.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the map object has no `setZoom` method according to the documentation page that you have given.

You can probably try redrawing the map using using `draw` method like this

```
var newZoom = 12;
map.draw(data, {showTip: true, zoom:newZoom,  mapType: 'normal', useMapTypeControl:true, enableScrollWheel:false});
```

Comment: Did it draw the map the first time ?

Comment: its drawing the map but zoom is not changing

Comment: try to unset the map variable and then redraw it ... it should work

Comment: I couldnt find any method which unsets the map ... you would probably need to draw the map again. Does that help @KousikChowdhury ?

Comment: i am doing like that. every time i am reseting the map with new coordinate. i have tried as you suggested but its not helping. i appreciate your courage.